# Scrolling RecyclerView manually does not update CoordinatorLayout , while scrolling by touch it update CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-appcompat

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <! -- Your Scrollable View -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                  ...
                  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                  ...
                  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

when i scoll the recyclerview by touch ( on screen) the scroll behaviour  works as expected , but when i scroll the recyclerview programmatically

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager());
        layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(spanCount * exactItemPos / mScrollPosState.rowHeight,
                -(exactItemPos % mScrollPosState.rowHeight));
```

the recyclerview scrolls toolbar does not

Answer (score 0):

You could put

```
    appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
```

before you do `scrollToPositionWithOffset`

Comment: I want the scrollToPositionWithOffset to change AppBarLayout , as if the user is scrolling , you got what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

CoordinatorLayout.Behaviour is works with only NestedScroll event. When you try to scroll RecyclerView programmatically it is treat as normal scroll.

Write below line to inform RecyclerView start NesteadScroll, With **ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL** and **ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH**

**ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL:**  Indicates scrolling along the vertical axis. 
**ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH:** Indicates that the input type for the gesture is caused by something which is not a user touching a screen. This is usually from a fling which is settling.

```
recycler_view.startNestedScroll(ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL, ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH)
recycler_view.smoothScrollBy(0,200)
```

Comment: I tried this and it works but there is one issue which is if you have BottomNav + AppBarLayout then only made a little scroll on RecyclerView and trigger this with `smoothScrollToPosition(0)` to scroll up, the RecyclerView does not scroll fully up thus it scrolls up but first item is still not visible.