# Scrolling Recycler View programmatically does not update CoordinatorLayout.Behaviour while scrolling it by touch update CoordinatorLayout.Behaviour

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I referred [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536464/scrolling-recyclerview-manually-does-not-update-coordinatorlayout-while-scroll) but no answers works for me. So basically I have a `BottomNavigationView` which hide on scroll down and show on scroll up. it works fine when I scroll Recycler View by touch but does not work when I scroll the `RecyclerView` programmatically. Seems like it does not trigger `CoordinatorLayout.Behaviour` when programmatically scrolled. In a certain case I have to open that fragment which contains `RecyclerView` with scroll to some position, and `BottomNavigationView` hiding it have to came back when user scroll up That means I don't want to hide visibility of `BottomNavigationView` just hide on scroll either scroll by programmatically or by touch.

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kliff.digitaldwarka.activity.MainActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/myAppBar"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:itemBackground="@android:color/white"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <com.appeaser.sublimenavigationviewlibrary.SublimeNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:snvHeaderLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:snvMenu="@menu/nav_menu"
    style="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
    app:snvItemTextColor="#555555"
    app:snvSubheaderItemTextColor="#555555"
    app:snvItemIconTint="#555555"
    app:snvBadgeTextColor="#555555"
    app:snvHintTextColor="#757575"
    app:snvHintTypefaceStyle="normal"
    app:snvBadgeTypefaceStyle="normal"
    app:snvSubheaderItemTypefaceStyle="normal"
    app:snvItemTypefaceStyle="normal" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

> fragment_category.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="1dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

> Code For scrolling

```
 mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(34); //specific postion
```

By scrolling this way how can I achive the behaviour. Any Help Would be appricited thanks.

Answer (score 3):

CoordinatorLayout.Behaviour is works with only NestedScroll event. When you try to scroll RecyclerView programmatically it is treat as normal scroll.

Write below line to inform RecyclerView start NesteadScroll, With **ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL** and **ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH**

**ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL:**  Indicates scrolling along the vertical axis. 
**ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH:** Indicates that the input type for the gesture is caused by something which is not a user touching a screen. This is usually from a fling which is settling.

```
recycler_view.startNestedScroll(ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL, ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH)
recycler_view.smoothScrollBy(0,200)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! When you answer a question you should include some kind of explanation, like what the author did wrong and what you did to fix it. I'm telling you this because your answer has been flagged as low-quality and is currently being reviewed. You can [edit] your answer by clicking the "Edit" button.

Answer (score 1):

For me nothing did work, until I wrapped Bhavesh Jabuvanis answer in a post

```
mRecyclerView?.post  {
  mRecyclerView?.startNestedScroll(ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL, ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH)
  mRecyclerView?.smoothScrollToPosition(scrollToPosition)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Its working for me. I am using the [BottomBar Library](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar).

```
public void showBottomBar(boolean show) {
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mBottomBar.getLayoutParams();
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior2 = params.getBehavior();
    if (behavior2 != null) {
        behavior2.onNestedFling(coordinator, mBottomBar, null, 0, show ? -10000 : 10000, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to hide the bottom bar programatically. I should follow the same scroll response whither scroll by touch or program

Comment: @zsmb13 Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

I have use this code please check if its suitable for you :-

activity_mail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.constraintlayout.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_scrolling.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.constraintlayout.ScrollingActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: RecyclerView also has its own Nested Srcoll view.. also if i put nested on top of recycler still the same issue..